# Why does this function return as undefined?

Tags: javascript

```
String.prototype.parse = function(f) {
    alert(this.replace(f, ""));
};
var a = "Hello World";
parse.apply(a, ["Hello"]);
```

Is the code correct?

Comment: Please ignore: [Standard C++ Iostreams and Locales: Advanced Programmer's Guide and Reference](http://books.google.com/books?id=5qybChHSk7QC&lpg=PA628&ots=dpgQaz4o6Z&dq=advanced%20file%20facets%20locale%20codecvt&pg=PR15#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, that’s not correct. The function is defined as `String.prototype.parse`, so it is not available as `parse` (in fact, `parse` is undefined).

You could run it like the following:

```
String.prototype.parse.apply(a, ["Hello"]);
```

But actually, the reason why you add the function to the prototype of String is that you extend String objects with that function. So you actually should just run the function like this:

```
a.parse("Hello");
```

#### edit:

Oh, and in response to your question title *“Why does this function return as undefined?”*: The function doesn’t return anything, because you don’t tell the function to return anything. You could for example define it like this to return the replaced string (instead of alerting it):

```
String.prototype.parse = function(f) {
    return this.replace(f, "");
};
```

And then you could alert the return value of the function:

```
alert(a.parse("Hello"));
```

Comment: What I'm actually trying to do is make any argument in "parse" be replaced with nothing. But it's not working.

Comment: @David: You can access all parameters passed to a function using the `arguments` array (it is automatically defined inside a function). You can loop through all elements and run the replacement for each element.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such variable `parse` defined in your code sample.  If you really want to `apply` the function later on, you should do this:

```
// Capture function as a local variable first
var parse = function(f) { alert(this.replace(f, "")); };
String.prototype.parse = parse;
```